# XSLT: for_each on two lists

Tags: for-loop, xslt, each

I got following source and I want to get these pairs

```
list/desc id=1 and rec/val id=1,
list/desc id=2 and rec/val id=2,
list/desc id=3 and rec/val id=3
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xxx>
    <yyy>
        <list>
            <desc id="1" name="Name1"/>
            <desc id="2" name="Name2"/>
            <desc id="3" name="Name3"/>
        </list>
        <rec>
            <val id="1">Value1</val>
            <val id="2"/>
            <val id="3">IValue3</val>
        </rec>
    </yyy>
</pxxx>
```

I tried for_each on `list/desc`, but that doesn't help.
Has someone an idea or a hint?

Comment: Do you want to transform your input XML into an output XML document? If so, can you please provide what you'd like the output to look like?

Comment: Which version of XSLT can you use? And what exactly do you want to do with the pairs, do you want to merge them into some new XML?

Comment: `<simpletable>
   <sthead>
    <stentry>Name</stentry>
    <stentry>Value</stentry>
   </sthead>
   <strow>
    <stentry>Name1</stentry>
     <stentry>Value1</stentry>
  </strow>
   <strow>
    <stentry>Name2</stentry>
     <stentry></stentry>
  </strow>
   <strow>
    <stentry>Name3</stentry>
     <stentry>Value3</stentry>
  </strow>
</simpletable>`

Comment: I use xslt2.0, perhast I could use xslt3.0 if there are speial features required.

Comment: The output is a simple table, values from <list> shoudl be column 1, values vom <rec> should be column 2

Comment: Are elements related by having the same @id value, or are they related by having the same position within their containing element?

Answer (score 2):

An XSLT-1.0 solution would be

```
<xsl:template match="/xxx/yyy">  
    <simpletable>
        <sthead>
            <stentry>Name</stentry>
            <stentry>Value</stentry>
        </sthead>
        <xsl:for-each select="list/desc[@id]">
            <strow>
                <stentry><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></stentry>
                <stentry><xsl:value-of select="../../rec/val[@id=current()/@id]/text()" /></stentry>
            </strow>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </simpletable>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<simpletable>
    <sthead>
        <stentry>Name</stentry>
        <stentry>Value</stentry>
    </sthead>
    <strow>
        <stentry>Name1</stentry>
        <stentry>Value1</stentry>
    </strow>
    <strow>
        <stentry>Name2</stentry>
        <stentry/>
    </strow>
    <strow>
        <stentry>Name3</stentry>
        <stentry>IValue3</stentry>
    </strow>
</simpletable>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess this would becomplicated because id is 1..n,

Comment: It wasn't necessary to mention each `@id` individually. I adapted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the XSLT 3 `xsl:merge` instruction

```
  <xsl:template match="yyy">
      <xsl:merge>
          <xsl:merge-source select="list/desc">
              <xsl:merge-key select="@id"/>
          </xsl:merge-source>
          <xsl:merge-source select="rec/val">
              <xsl:merge-key select="@id"/>
          </xsl:merge-source>
          <xsl:merge-action>
              <strow>
                  <stentry>{current-merge-group()[1]/@name}</stentry>
                  <stentry>{current-merge-group()[2]}</stentry>
              </strow>
          </xsl:merge-action>
      </xsl:merge>
  </xsl:template>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEU which transforms

```
<xxx>
    <yyy>
        <list>
            <desc id="1" name="Name1"/>
            <desc id="2" name="Name2"/>
            <desc id="3" name="Name3"/>
        </list>
        <rec>
            <val id="1">Value1</val>
            <val id="2"/>
            <val id="3">IValue3</val>
        </rec>
    </yyy>
</xxx>
```

into

```
<strow>
   <stentry>Name1</stentry>
   <stentry>Value1</stentry>
</strow>
<strow>
   <stentry>Name2</stentry>
   <stentry/>
</strow>
<strow>
   <stentry>Name3</stentry>
   <stentry>IValue3</stentry>
</strow>
```

Full minimal sample is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="yyy">
      <xsl:merge>
          <xsl:merge-source select="list/desc">
              <xsl:merge-key select="@id"/>
          </xsl:merge-source>
          <xsl:merge-source select="rec/val">
              <xsl:merge-key select="@id"/>
          </xsl:merge-source>
          <xsl:merge-action>
              <strow>
                  <stentry>{current-merge-group()[1]/@name}</stentry>
                  <stentry>{current-merge-group()[2]}</stentry>
              </strow>
          </xsl:merge-action>
      </xsl:merge>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```